# Reading parameters from AWS Lambda function in Golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I am passing in events into a AWS lambda function from a `events.json` file and parsing it in a function handler.

The code is:

```
type MyEvent struct {
    Param string `json:"param1"`
    Token string `json:"token"`
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}

func Handler(ctx context.Context, evt json.RawMessage) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

    var myEvent MyEvent
    json.Unmarshal(evt, &myEvent)

    fmt.Println(myEvent.Token)
    fmt.Println(len(myEvent.Token))

    // rest of the code is here
}
```

The `event.json` file is:

```
{
    "param1": "Param",
    "token": "35c760f4-b3dc-4657-b4f3–2c6566d4f42e"
}
```

The output of the function is

```
35c760f4-b3dc-4657-b4f3–2c6566d4f42e
38
```

The value of the token that is being printed is correct but the length is not. The length of the token is 36 but is being interpreted/printed as 38.

Why is this happening ?

PS: I am using the AWS SAM cli to run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running

```
func main() {
    s := "35c760f4-b3dc-4657-b4f3–2c6566d4f42e"
    fmt.Println(len(s))
}
```

`"–"` this character comes up as a length of 3. It's just a weird character. Has the character code of `8211`, you want `45`

https://unicodelookup.com/#8211/1

https://unicodelookup.com/#45/1

```
len(strings.ReplaceAll(myEvent.Token, "–", "-"))
```

will give you the right length